# How can I render a custom view in a UIScrollView at varying zoom levels without distorting the view?

Tags: cocoa-touch

The scenario:

I have a custom view (a subclass of UIView) that draws a game board. To enable the ability to zoom into, and pan around, the board I added my view as a subview of UIScrollView. This kind of works, but the game board is being rendered incorrectly. Everything is kind of fuzzy, and nothing looks right.

The question:

How can I force my view to be redrawn correctly ay varying scales? I'm providing my view with the current scale and sending it a setNeedsDisplay message after the scroll view is done zooming in/out, but the game board is still being rendered incorrectly. My view should be redrawing the game board depending on the zoom level, but this isn't happening. Does the scroll view perform a generic transformation on subviews? Is there a way to disable this behavior?

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is to render your game board at a really high resolution, then let the ScrollView handle scaling it *down* to your display size automatically.

Basically, set the contentSize of your ScrollView to something big (say 1024x1024), and make your game board one giant view inside it, of the same size (say 1024x1024).  Then simply let the ScrollView handle *all* the scaling questions.  You don't even need to intercept setNeedsDisplay or anything; as far as your game is concerned, it's just always rendering at the highest resolution.